# Installing kernel headers on CentOS 8 for VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, header-files, centos8

This is a follow-up to

[RHEL: This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49369065/rhel-this-system-is-currently-not-set-up-to-build-kernel-modules)

I get the same error messages running `/sbin/vboxconfig` as over there.

I have the following:

```
pkg $ uname -r
4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64
pkg $ rpm -qa| grep kernel-devel
kernel-devel-4.18.0-193.19.1.el8_2.x86_64
```

So the devel package is for a subversion (pun intended) of the installed kernel. That version is installed when I do `dnf install kernel-devel` and I cannot install by the command suggested with `$( uname -r)`.

What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/597701/46710

> Followed by reboot in case a new kernel gets installed should fix it for you.

helped: the reboot solved my problem, `/sbin/vboxconfig` ran smoothly afterwards.